# Building a PAM module and install into /lib/security

Tags: installation, autotools, libtool, pam

I am currently trying to build and install a PAM module using autotools. While the building process goes smoothly, the `install` target does not behave quite as I'd like it to.

```
$ make install
bash ../libtool --mode=install install -c pam_mymodule.la '/usr/local/lib'
```

<sup>*In the above piece of output, I removed absolute paths to GNU executables.*</sup>

Two things are bothering me in this call:

- `make` tries to move the `pam_mymodule.la` file, while I'd rather like it to move the `.libs/pam_mymodule.so` file.
- `make` tries to move it into `/usr/local/lib`, while `/lib/security` is a more appropriate choice for PAM modules.

How can I change the install configuration?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669303/gnu-autotools-install-binaries-into-bin-sbin-usr-bin-and-usr-sbin-intera

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address your two things in order:

- The `libtool` script intercepts that `install` instruction and also installs the `.so` file in the appropriate place.
- It's putting it in `/usr/local/lib` probably because you listed it in `lib_LTLIBRARIES` (although I can't be sure if you don't show your code) and your `--prefix` is set to its default of `/usr/local`.

This last one is difficult since Autotools' official stance is that all user-installed programs belong in `/usr`, whereas many other tools expect things to be in `/lib/something`. Here's one way to do it, that I personally consider wrong:

```
# Don't do this
libsecuritydir = /lib/security
libsecurity_LTLIBRARIES = pam_mymodule.la
```

This bypasses `--prefix`, which will go horribly, horribly wrong if you try to do a local install of your package without writing directly into your live system, which, trust me, you will want to do at some point. It will also prevent you from packaging your program in most Linux distributions' packaging systems.

The correct way is to push the responsibility onto whoever installs the package: add a `--with-libsecuritydir` argument to `configure.ac` using `AC_ARG_WITH` and let that default to `$(libdir)/security`:

```
AC_ARG_WITH([libsecuritydir],
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-libsecuritydir],
        [Directory for PAM modules, pass /lib/security for live install])],
    [], [with_libsecuritydir='$(libdir)/security'])
AC_SUBST([libsecuritydir], [$with_libsecuritydir])
```

and then just do

```
libsecurity_LTLIBRARIES = pam_mymodule.la
```

in `Makefile.am`.

When you want to install a live version directly into your system (or are building a binary package) pass `--with-libsecuritydir=/lib/security` to `configure`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I was afraid I would face some portability-related issue here, but using an option seems like the best solution indeed. Just a little note though: your `AS_IF` might want to test against `x` instead of `xno`, otherwise `libsecuritydir` will remain empty when the option isn't specified at all (unless you explicitly use `--with-libsecuritydir=no`.

Comment: True, I should have used the fourth _action-if-not-given_ parameter of `AC_ARG_WITH` to do that. I'll edit the answer.